# Backup MSSQL DB Schema

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-server-2008, t-sql, database-backups

I'm trying to back up my production database to my local dev machine with the following constraints:

1. It will be a regular backup, so using the UI should (ideally?) be avoided.
2. Some tables are marked to be deleted, so these should not be included in the backup.
3. I would like to be able to pass the solution (file/package/etc) to other members of the team and they should only have to change a couple of variables in one file and then they can execute and get their own backup.
4. The DB is over 100GB and contains data that I won't need. I have identified the top largest tables and would only like to take say 5k rows from each - this should provide me with enough data for my purposes and limit space used on my local drives.

I have tried beginning with backing up the schema only using the following methods:

1. Using the UI to backup Schema only (Tasks -> Generate Scripts)
   Get the following error:

`Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException: Discover dependencies failed. ---> System.ArgumentException: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'Server[@Name='PRODSQL']/Database[@Name='Database1']/UnresolvedEntity[@Name='SomeObjectName' and @Schema='Some.Schema.SomeObjectName']' Key being added: 'Server[@Name='PRODSQL']/Database[@Name='Database1']/UnresolvedEntity[@Name='SomeObjectName' and @Schema='Some.Schema.SomeObjectName']' at System.Collections.SortedList.Add(Object key, Object value) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DependencyTree..ctor(Urn[] urns, DependencyChainCollection dependencies, Boolean fParents, Server server) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DependencyWalker.DiscoverDependencies(Urn[] urns, Boolean parents) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlScriptPublish.GeneratePublishPage.worker_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e) at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)`

So I moved on.

2. Tasks -> Copy Database

   I get a message saying there is not enough space on disk
3. Extract Data-tier Application

   Get same error as in 1. above.
4. Powershell script, and a batch file calling sqlcmd on the generated .sql files after the PS script was run.

I was sure this method would work and it took me 2 days to get this far, but still working through multiple errors.

Basically I am doing the following:

1. Create db objects from the source DB (Schemas, SPs, Tables, Views, UDFs, Triggers, Indexes) and output them to .sql files - Roughly followed http://cfmumbojumbo.com/index.cfm/coding/using-powershell-to-backup-your-stored-procedures-and-triggers/ with some more work added.
2. If the database already exists on my server, kill, drop, then recreate it (DropCreate.sql):

   ```
   IF(db_id(@DatabaseName) IS NOT NULL)
   BEGIN
   DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(max)
   SELECT @SQL = COALESCE(@SQL,'') + 'Kill ' + Convert(VARCHAR, SPId) + ';'
   FROM MASTER..SysProcesses
   WHERE DBId = DB_ID(@DatabaseName) AND SPId <> @@SPId
   EXEC(@SQL);
   END 

   DROP DATABASE MYDATABASE

   CREATE DATABASE MYDATABASE ON PRIMARY (...)
   ```

The .bat file is essentially doing this

```
sqlcmd -S %Server% -U %UserName% -P %Password% -i C:\Database\DatabaseScripts\TestDatabase\DropCreateDB.sql

#loop through and execute multiple .sql files in the directory
for /f %f in (`dir /b C:\Database\DatabaseScripts\TestDatabase\2018-04-18-15-13-13\StoredProcedures\`) do sqlcmd -S %Server% -d %Database% -U %UserName% -P %Password% -i %f
#Just one sql file in this directory, execute it
sqlcmd -S %Server% -d %Database% -U %UserName% -P %Password% -i C:\Database\DatabaseScripts\TestDatabase\2018-04-18-15-13-13\Schemas\AllSchemas.sql
sqlcmd -S %Server% -d %Database% -U %UserName% -P %Password% -i C:\Database\DatabaseScripts\TestDatabase\2018-04-18-15-13-13\Tables\AllTables.sql 
.............
```

The latest error I'm experiencing is:

> Changed database context to 'master'.
>   Msg 6107, Level 14, State 1, Server MYSERVER, Line 1
>   Only user processes can be killed.
>   do was unexpected at this time.

Everywhere I turn I am experiencing new errors and have spent over 2 days on it, and I haven't even got to getting the data yet..

TLDR: Is there any easier way backup MSSQL Db schema and top n rows of data from certain tables?

Comment: Creating scripts and/or extracting a database project is a sane way to go, but either SMO contains a problem or your database does (not everything possible to subject a database to at runtime can later be scripted correctly). Try [SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017) and importing your database into a project. (That is a one-time UI step.) Try compiling the project and see if you get errors about ill-defined objects that might block regular script generation as well. For extra peace of mind, run `DBCC CHECKDB`.

Comment: To recreate a database, incidentally, it's more sensible to use `USE master; ALTER DATABASE myDatabase SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; DROP DATABASE;` rather than go off and explicitly kill sessions. A DACPAC, if you could get it to work, will take care of this stuff automatically (if you tell it to; by default it will upgrade the existing DB).